# Swap node in json object

Tags: c#, json

I have json object which contains follow string:

```
{  
   "id":"7081236211",
   "name":"TURYSTYCZNY PLECAK WISPORT REINDEER 75L OLIVE",
   "category":{  
      "id":"147827"
   },
   "parameters":[  
      {  
         "id":"11323",
         "valuesIds":[  
            "11323_1"
         ],
         "values":[  

         ],
         "rangeValue":null
      },
      {  
         "id":"13949",
         "valuesIds":[  
            "13949_225446"
         ],
         "values":[  

         ],
         "rangeValue":null
      }
   ]
}
```

I would like to change "parameter" node on this json string which is generate dynamically and number of nodes in parameters is diffrent:

```
\"parameters\": [
    {
      \"id\": \"11345\",
      \"valuesIds\": [],
      \"values\": [
        \"23424\",
        \"43656\"
       ],
      \"rangeValue\": null
    }]
```

So how can i do this?

Comment: You need a json library, such as json.net.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Newtonsoft.Json library.

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(input);
var paramToAdd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parameter>(paramToAddJson);
obj.parameters.Add(paramToAdd);

var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
output.Dump();
```

---

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Category category { get; set; }
    public List<Parameter> parameters { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class Parameter
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string[] valuesIds { get; set; }
    public string[] values { get; set; }
    public object rangeValue { get; set; }
}
```

[Full Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0Q7wep)